# Does Cyanogenmod 12.1 support the Samsung S4 Mini Smart Cover?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini, smart-cover

I have successfully installed the Cyanogenmod 12.1 (version as of 11.07.2015) for my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini and I was wondering if it supports the Samsung Galaxy S4 MINI I9192 S-View Premium Flip Cover Black, as can be seen here when it is closed: [image]

It currently does not show the screen like this when closed, but parts of the vanilla Cyanogenmod screen which does not help at all. Any ideas how to change that behaviour?

Comment: There is an app called "Hall Monitor" made by Durka but it will only work on cm11 and not cm12.

Answer (score 1):

Since CyanogenMod is close to Stock Android.
**The answer will have to be no.**

However though, there are many apps that bring this function.

Comment: Hi, simpletool, thank you for your answer. Are you able maybe to name one of these apps you mentioned?